# How to make this short in Grails or Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, grails, groovy

I've got query that looks something like this:

```
SomeDomain.executeQuery("""
    from
        SomeDomain x
    where
        x.linkToSomeA = coalesce(:a, x.linkToSomeA) and
        x.linkToSomeB = coalesce(:b, x.linkToSomeB) and
        ...
    """,
    [a: someA, b: someB, ...]
)
```

The intended behaviour is as follows: once `null` is supplied for a criterion parameter, this criterion should be ignored. If anything other than `null` is supplied, the criterion is used.

Everything would work fine, except that Hibernate doesn't allow supplying `null` where domain class instances are expected. So in the end this is not a valid query (in fact `NullPointerException` will be thrown if any `null`s are supplied).

I haven't found any way to rewrite this without using a ton of `if-else`. Does anybody have any idea how to make this about **equally brief and valid** at the same time?

NOTE: The real query is more complicated than that so please, do not suggest rewriting this using anything else than `executeQuery`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is generally for this kind of problem that the Criteria api is used: it allows building a query dynamically:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(SomeDomain.class, "x");
if (a != null) {
    c.add(Restrictions.eq("x.linkToSomeA", a));
}
if (b != null) {
    c.add(Restrictions.eq("x.linkToSomeB", b));
}
// ...
```

This answer doesn't follow your request of not using anything else than `executeQuery`, but you might also ask how to build a house using nothing else than a screwdriver, and the best answer would still be "buy some other tools").

Comment: The problem is the last time I checked I wasn't able to use criteria because of a bug. But maybe you're right and there really isn't any way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if you can use a map and `findAll()`, like this:

```
def query = [
    'a': 'x.linkToSomeA = :a',
    'b': 'x.linkToSomeB = :b'
].findAll{ k, q -> params[k] != null }.values().join(' and ')

SomeDomain.executeQuery("""
    from
        SomeDomain x
    where
        ${query}
    """,
    params
)
```

This should return a list of all query elements that have non-null parameters in the params map (this should be changed to match the map used in the query).  It's a simple job of filtering out based on the "key" of the main map, then joining the values with `and`.

Note, there's one potential issue, and that's if there's no params at all.  In that case, you'll want to check that `query` is non-empty or provide a fallback method.